# How to set Configuring the nodes by JSON

Tags: java, selenium-grid

please help. 
How can I set properties for nodes by JSON?
I have 3 .jason files with properties for Chrome node, FireFox node, Safari node, they are in my project folder (src/test/resources/). I execute command in my bash:

java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar -role node -nodeConfig nodeFirfox.json

But console return:

> org.openqa.grid.common.exception.GridConfigurationException: Error
>   with the JSON of the config : nodeFirfox is not a valid resource.     at
>   org.openqa.grid.common.RegistrationRequest.loadFromJSON(RegistrationRequest.java:564)
>     at
>   org.openqa.grid.common.RegistrationRequest.build(RegistrationRequest.java:375)
>     at
>   org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncher$3.launch(GridLauncher.java:89)
>     at org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncher.main(GridLauncher.java:127)
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: nodeFirfox is not a valid
>   resource.     at
>   org.openqa.grid.common.JSONConfigurationUtils.loadJSON(JSONConfigurationUtils.java:54)
>     at
>   org.openqa.grid.common.RegistrationRequest.loadFromJSON(RegistrationRequest.java:540)
>     ... 3 more

How must I validate this .json(s) configs?

Thanks everybody in advance

Comment: Please add you json file.

Answer (score 0):

The error `org.openqa.grid.common.exception.GridConfigurationException: Error with the JSON of the config : nodeFirfox is not a valid resource.` basically is saying that the file `nodeFirfox.json` is not a valid file in the file system. You should give either a proper relative path (or) an absolute path to where the node configuration file exists via the parameter `-nodeConfig`. Please fix the path and try again.